# Check if integer has some character content in java

Tags: java, validation, integer

Whenever I am trying to lookup on the internet to see if an int value which is accepted from a userfield has some characters like A-z or any special characters, all the sites happen to presume that the input is in the form of String.
Function

```
boolean numberValidation(int number){
    if number has characters mentioned above, return false
   else return true
}
```

Comment: Hint: `number` has type `int`, it **can't** contain alphanumeric characters.

Comment: How can an int have characters in it?  Impossible.  You must have meant String.  In that case, regular expressions are one way to do it.

Comment: I cannot understand your problem. Integers are numeric representated and characters(also numbers) alphanumeric.clarify it: You have an inputfield which accepts alphanumeric inputs but  you only want to allow the numeric ones in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for hexadecimal numbers with any digit `> 9`, you can do it as such:

```
// hex representation of -889275714
int i = 0xcafebabe;
// just 1
int j = 1;
// represents both as hexadecimal String representations
String is = Integer.toHexString(i);
String ij = Integer.toHexString(j);
// pattern to check for letters
Pattern alpha = Pattern.compile("[a-z]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
System.out.printf("\"%s\" contains characters, \"%s\" does not.%n", is, ij);
```

**Output**

```
"cafebabe" contains characters, "1" does not.
```

**Note**

For `String`s representing numbers, as shown in other answers, use `Integer.parseInt` and catch a `NumberFormatException`.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to use the pattern alpha to check against integer. Something similar to Boolean valid = password.matches(passwordRegex); ?

Comment: @Kernelfreak not sure what you mean? Maybe a new question might be more suitable for this?

Answer (score 2):

In that case, the compiler will complain about the parameter passed.

If the parameter was a String and you want to detect if the String is a valid integer, you can parse it controlling exceptions. The following code is a suggestion:

```
boolean numberValidation(String number){
    try{
        Integer.parseInt(number);
        return true;
    }catch(NumberFormatException e){
        return false;
    }
}
```

Regards,

Comment: Nedless to say that it can be done with regex too, but it is a bit complex way (but a cool way :)).

Answer (score 1):

Try to parse it and if exception occurs return false else return true

```
boolean numberValidation(String supposedNumber) {
    boolean flag = false;
    int x;
    try {
        x = Integer.parseInt(supposedNumber);
        flag = true;
    } catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
        flag = false;
    }
    return flag;
}
```

Comment: 1. It doesn't compile, 2. Just-code answers won't help the OP.

Comment: Don't see why this would be downvoted.  Perfectly acceptable, although I'm not crazy about using exceptions this way.

Comment: @Nabin catch without exception?

Comment: @BackSlash You must be kidding me.. You look for code accuracy too?

Comment: @BackSlash I am not quite sure if the mentioned exception is spelled correct :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I think you want:

```
public boolean isNumber(String value) { 
    return Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(value).matches();
}
```

Comment: Why not just `value.matches("\\d+")`?